# Is it possible to alter the test used by NUnit when returning a value from a test

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a set of tests which are verifying a contract with an external API. I want the test class to implement the contract interface so that if it is ever changed the test class itself enforces that tests are written for any new methods.

So something like

```
public interface IExternalThing {
  Dictionary<string, int> GetSomeValues(int id);
}

[TestFixture]
public class ContractVerification : IExternalThing {
  private realExternalThing = new ExternalThing();

  private static IEnumerable GetValuesSource {
    get
    {
      yield return new TestCaseData(0).Returns(
        new Dictionary<string, int> {
          {"thing", 1}
        }
      );
    }
  }

  [Test]
  [TestCaseSource("GetValuesSource")]
  public Dictionary<string, int> GetSomeValues(int id) {
      return realExternalThing.GetSomeValues(id);
  }
}
```

This approach has worked so far but as this method returns a Dictionary NUnit is reporting failure with the message:

```
> Expected and actual are both
> <System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32]>
> with 1 elements
```

I suppose I could approach this another way but if I could just ask NUnit to test `Is.EquivalentTo` instead of simple equality that would be fantastic.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.5 - CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent()

Comment: OK sorry, I am probably misunderstanding. Could you maybe expand you example code to something that compiles and exhibits the failure?

Comment: So, your answer was terrible - please avoid just dumping a link into an answer and explain why you think that link leads to the answer. However, your advice to write actual code and not pseudocode I followed (and normally do anyway - damn my laziness today) and it highlighted that actually NUnit does use the appropriate equality test and I'm a numpty because I wasn't actually providing two equivalent dictionaries despite being sure I was. So you can totally have the points because you lead me to solve my problem. :)